# Click event is happening in Android chrome but not in ios safari

Tags: java, ios, selenium-webdriver, safari, appium

This is my code in java.

```
 @TimeIt(key = "click")
  private void clickEvent(String uiIdentifierVariableName, boolean retry) throws Exception {
    
      findElement(uiIdentifierVariableName);
      WebElement webElement = ensureElementClickable(uiIdentifierVariableName);

      webElement.click(
    
  }
```

This is my html content

```
<div _ngcontent-akc-c53="" class="nav ng-star-inserted is-mobile" bis_skin_checked="1" style="border-color: rgb(194, 204, 216);">
   <div _ngcontent-akc-c53="" class="mobile-side-nav ng-star-inserted" bis_skin_checked="1">
      <div _ngcontent-akc-c53="" class="side-container-bg ng-star-inserted" bis_skin_checked="1" style="display: block;"></div>
      <div _ngcontent-akc-c53="" id="mySidenav" class="side-container ng-star-inserted" bis_skin_checked="1" style="width: 185px;">
         <div _ngcontent-akc-c53="" class="responsive-side-background ng-star-inserted" bis_skin_checked="1"></div>
         <!---->
         <a _ngcontent-akc-c53="" class="menu-item ng-star-inserted" style="border-color: rgb(194, 204, 216);">
            <div _ngcontent-akc-c53="" class="icon search_icon" bis_skin_checked="1"></div>
            <span _ngcontent-akc-c53="" class="text"> Search </span><!---->
         </a>
         <!----><!---->
         <a _ngcontent-akc-c53="" class="menu-item active ng-star-inserted" style="border-color: rgb(194, 204, 216);">
            <div _ngcontent-akc-c53="" class="icon home_icon active" bis_skin_checked="1"></div>
            <span _ngcontent-akc-c53="" class="text"> Home </span>
            <div _ngcontent-akc-c53="" class="nav__selected-item-triangle ng-star-inserted" bis_skin_checked="1" style="background-position: left 0% center;"></div>
            <!---->
         </a>
         <!----><!---->
         <a _ngcontent-akc-c53="" class="menu-item ng-star-inserted" style="border-color: rgb(194, 204, 216);">
            <div _ngcontent-akc-c53="" class="icon movie_icon" bis_skin_checked="1"></div>
            <span _ngcontent-akc-c53="" class="text"> Movies </span><!---->
         </a>
         <!----><!---->
         <a _ngcontent-akc-c53="" class="menu-item ng-star-inserted" style="border-color: rgb(194, 204, 216);">
            <div _ngcontent-akc-c53="" class="icon live_icon" bis_skin_checked="1"></div>
            <span _ngcontent-akc-c53="" class="text"> Live Channels </span><!---->
         </a>
         <!----><!---->
         <a _ngcontent-akc-c53="" class="menu-item ng-star-inserted" style="border-color: rgb(194, 204, 216);">
            <div _ngcontent-akc-c53="" class="icon stories_icon" bis_skin_checked="1"></div>
            <span _ngcontent-akc-c53="" class="text"> Stories </span><!---->
         </a>
         <!----><!---->
         <a _ngcontent-akc-c53="" class="menu-item ng-star-inserted" style="border-color: rgb(194, 204, 216);">
            <div _ngcontent-akc-c53="" class="icon kids_icon" bis_skin_checked="1"></div>
            <span _ngcontent-akc-c53="" class="text"> Kids </span><!---->
         </a>
         <!----><!----><!----><!---->
      </div>
      <div _ngcontent-akc-c53="" class="mobile-toggle ng-star-inserted" bis_skin_checked="1">
         <div _ngcontent-akc-c53="" id="hamburger" class="hamburger-icon change" bis_skin_checked="1">
            <div _ngcontent-akc-c53="" class="bar1 mobile" bis_skin_checked="1"></div>
            <div _ngcontent-akc-c53="" class="bar2 mobile" bis_skin_checked="1"></div>
            <div _ngcontent-akc-c53="" class="bar3 mobile" bis_skin_checked="1"></div>
         </div>
         <div _ngcontent-akc-c53="" class="home_icon hover icon" bis_skin_checked="1" style="opacity: 1;"></div>
      </div>
      <!---->
   </div>
   <!----><!---->
   <div _ngcontent-akc-c53="" class="right-container" bis_skin_checked="1">
      <!---->
      <a _ngcontent-akc-c53="" class="menu-item menu-item__profile ng-star-inserted">
         <div _ngcontent-akc-c53="" class="icon profile_icon" bis_skin_checked="1"></div>
         <span _ngcontent-akc-c53="" class="text menu-item__profile-text">Profiles</span>
      </a>
      <!---->
   </div>
</div>
```

This is opening on click of nav bar now when I am passing this xPath in  //span[contains(text(),'Search')]

My test cases are getting pass and appium log also I can see this is clickable. But acutally I am not able to navigate to Search Button. What could be possible issue.
Not even search in whole navigation popup only I am not able to click. while I am using browser stack.
This issue is happening in ios webview safari browser. same thing is working fine in android chrome. s

Comment: Please edit this question, the language is incorrect and should be fixed

Answer (score 0):

```
@TimeIt(key = "click")
```

private void clickEvent(String uiIdentifierVariableName, boolean retry) throws Exception {

```
  findElement(uiIdentifierVariableName);
  WebElement webElement = ensureElementClickable(uiIdentifierVariableName);

   webElement.click();
```

}

may be you are missing closing paranthesis in webelement.click();